# How to unpack a pandas Panel created with a dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas, panel

I have several `.txt` files in a subdirectoy, `/subdirect/`

These files are

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
...
```

Using glob, I can put these into a three-dimensional panel, using the filename as the key for key-value pairs.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

dataframe = {filename: pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in glob.glob('*.txt') # dictionary
data = pd.Panel.from_dict(dataframe) # create panel
```

Now, I would like to unpack these files to manipulate each DataFrame individually and plot data.

```
for fname in data:
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    df['total_sum'] = df[["column1", "column2", "column3"]].sum(axis=1)  # sum total reads
    df.plot(kind='bar')
```

However, I do not seem to be unpacking the panel correctly as the dimensions have completely changed.

How does one unpack a pandas Panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reading the data files individually instead, since you don't seem to be interested in the `Panel` structure per se:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['total_sum'] = df[["column1", "column2", "column3"]].sum(axis=1)  # sum total reads
    df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Alternatively, take a look at [`pd.Panel.to_frame()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.to_frame.html) to convert `Panel` to `DataFrame`. For instance, with a `Panel` from a `dict` with two `DataFrames`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(20, 10)))

panel = pd.Panel.from_dict({'1': df, '2': df.add(10)})

<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 20 (major_axis) x 10 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 1 to 2
Major_axis axis: 0 to 19
Minor_axis axis: 0 to 9
```

Using `to_frame()` gets you a long-format `DataFrame` with two columns and a `MultiIndex` with length of `row` x `column`. To plot, you could iterate over the `columns` of `data_frame` using `.items()` and use `.unstack()` to convert into format suitable for plotting:

```
data_frame = panel.to_frame()

MultiIndex: 200 entries, (0, 0) to (19, 9)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
1    200 non-null float64
2    200 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 4.7+ KB
None

for i, data in data_frame.items():
    data.unstack().plot()
```

On performance - if you start from a panel, summing there is faster than grouping and unstacking. It's also faster than summing an individual dataframe.

```
%timeit panel.sum(axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 111 µs per loop

%timeit panel.to_frame().groupby(data_frame.columns, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.unstack(0).sum(axis=1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.63 ms per loop

df = data_frame.unstack(0)
%timeit df.loc[:, '1'].sum(axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 409 µs per loop
```

Comment: How would you write the `for` statement above if you used `pd.Panel.to_frame()`?
Is there a difference in performance usually one data structure over another, a `panel` or `glob`?

Comment: See update on how to use `to_frame()`. `glob` just parses the filenames, you'd use this either way. Question is whether to combine the files into a panel first to then split back into dataframes, or read individually right away. Latter probably more efficient.

Comment: One last question: in the function using `glob`, I sum total reads with `df['total_sum'] = df[["column1", "column2", "column3"]].sum(axis=1) `. Wouldn't that be more efficient with a huge dataframe using `panel.to_frame()`? Do you know the performance between the two?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would unpack the files as a flat file and add the filename as a column.  You can now create a MultiIndex using the filename and whatever attributes you have in the dataframe.

Panels were used before MultiIndex functionality was improved.  Flat is better than nested.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df['filename'] = filename
    dfs.append(df)
dfs = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```